# How can we pass the parameter from jQuery Dialog and change the content of the html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui-dialog

I am looking to dynamically change the image shown in the jQuery Dialog. I am trying to pass the ‘image path’ as parameter which will be used to change the image shown in the jQuery dialog. Please! Check my code below.
By default, it will show ‘images/firstImage.jpg’ in the jQuery Dialog. Now, I am trying to change it to ‘images/secondImage.jpg’ through jQuery Dialog parameter.

```js
 <link href="jquery/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // this initializes the dialog (and uses some common options that I do)
            $("#dialog").dialog(
                {
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal: true,
                    show: "blind",
                    hide: "blind",
                    width: "50%",
                    height: "auto",
                    resizable: false,
                    position: 'center',
                    overflow: "hidden",
                });
        });

        function OpenGallary(photoSrc) {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open").data("param", photoSrc);
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<body>
    <a onclick="OpenGallary('images/secondImage.jpg')">Click ME</a>
    <div id="dialog" title="Photo Gallary">
        <div id="aa" style="width: 800px;">
            hello this is my world.
        </div>
        <p>
            <img src="images/firstImage.jpg" />
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function OpenGallary (I think you mean Gallery, but I digress) is just setting the data attribute on the dialog div, which is not going to affect the image tag.

The OpenGallary function can be changed to something like:

```
function OpenGallary(photoSrc) {
    // Change the src attribute directly on the img in the dialog:
    $("#dialog img").attr("src", photoSrc);
    // Now that the dialog html is updated, open the dialog:
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
}
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may want to select the img directly with an id on the tag - the selector used above is just for working with the existing html.